# reading system.servicemodel section from database

Tags: wcf

We have a dynamically composed application, in which user can add services and operations. This application is installed on a server cluster.

Since adding services to application involves so much writing to `web.config`, i was wondering if its possible to read `system.servicemodel` section from a database instead of `web.config`.

Seems like microsoft's implementation of configuration is very tightly coupled with where its stored.

Comment: Not that I know of - I've tried several things, researched it quite a bit - without much success. You can of course build together your own config system for WCF and build up your bindings etc. in code - but I didn't find any way of putting a standard .NET config section into a database and have .NET interpret it from there :-( No provider model or anything seems to be supported :-(

Comment: @marc_s: Have you tried something like it is provided below? Care to share facts you found out during your research?

Comment: @rest wing: sure - send me an e-mail - it's in my profile....

Comment: marc_s, were you able to get solution for this working ? I couldnt find email in Rest Wings profile

Answer (score 0):

There is no "out-of-the-box" way to do that. However, it is possible.

Few feet below, `Configuration` class uses `FileStream` instance where it actually can use any `Stream`. That particular step can be replaced with custom implementation of `IInternalConfigHost` interface (a lot of properties and methods to implement there).

Particularly interesting are `OpenStreamForRead` and `OpenStreamForWrite`, both are returning `Stream` instances. There you can put logic to pull XML of configuration sections from database into `ConfigurationSection` instances and to put `ConfigurationSection` instances as XML into database.

The next step is to create an instance of `Configuration` class. However, here we must get dirty because its constructor never leaves the `System.Configuration` kingdom. The need to use reflection to reach and use it. I suggest implementation of `IInternalConfigConfigurationFactory` to wrap the reflection magic.

```
Configuration Create( Type typeConfigHost,
    params object[] hostInitConfigurationParams );
```

As first parameter pass the type of implemented configuration host.

After we have `Configuration` instance, we can use it a custom `ServiceHost`, `ChannelFactory<T>` and `DuplexChannelFactory<T>`.